# Swift 3 - set nested dictionary to UserDefaults - Crashes

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I am trying to save a nested dictionary into `UserDefaults` but whenever I try to save I get a crash:

Why is this crashing? In swift 2 it was working just fine

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

this is my function:

```
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

GetNewsFeed.getAllNews { (result) in
            if let resData = result.arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                self.defaults.set(self.arrRes, forKey: self.ARRAY_CACHE) // ERROR
                self.defaults.synchronize()

                print(self.defaults.dictionary(forKey: self.ARRAY_CACHE))
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the reason of the exception? Consider that in many cases a dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to answer with just that snippet. I think the following line returns a nil value and causing the crash in the later line:

```
 self.arrRes = resData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
```

Use following optional chaining technique and see if that solves :

```
if let data = resData as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
      self.defaults.set(data, forKey: self.ARRAY_CACHE)
} else {
      debugPrint("invalid data")
}
```